# Cant link images on subdomain

Tags: php, html

Can someone explain why linking local image files doesnt work under subdomain.

I have a website:

> http://example.com/site/index.php

Icons and images are under icons directory.

> http://example.com/site/icons/icon.png

I include them in site like this:

```
<img src="icons/icon.png">
```

This works fine when accessing site from first url.

However, when i use subdomain:

> http://site.example.com

Icons doesnt display anymore.

I notice that even in browser, it doesnt exist.

> http://site.example.com/icons/icon.png

Happy new year!

Comment: Because, quite simply, example.com and site.example.com are different web addresses. They are not the same website.

Comment: Yes, but they load index.php from same place, so why cant i access icons dir under subdomain ?

Comment: Unless the subdomain is set up to mirror the base domain, then both domains would have their own index.php file. example.com/index.php and site.example.com/index.php are also different files (although could well contain the same content).

Comment: How are the domains / vhosts setup? You probably want aliases for the sub-domains if you want to provide the exact  same content.

Comment: Subdomain is created on directadmin control panel, wich links to corresponding directory so, site.example.com would link to example.com/site

Answer (score 0):

You need to check where your subdomain is pointing to. It seems from your description that the folder which it is pointing to contains an index.php file that is identical to the index.php file in the `site` folder, which gives you the feeling that the subdomain is actually pointing to the `site` folder, but it's not.

You need to change the subdomain in the control panel to point to the value `/site`. Notice the forward slash.